# windows.kendo is undefiend on kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i get this error on  kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js :
windows.kendo is undefiend .

my cod :

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might want to visit [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the include for `kendo.web.min.js` before the include for `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`. It needs to be there before the MVC stuff is included.

Comment: no , i tried this before . i change version jquery-1.7. to jquery-1.8 . and jquery-1.9. but didn't work .